# Why Jenkins sends my email template as a plain text without script evaluation?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

My Jenkins email-ext template is:

```
$DEFULAT_CONTENT

Changes:
${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="%a: %r %p \n--\"%m\", pathFormat="\n\t- %p"}
```

And what I get in a notification email is:

```
XXX - Build # 34 - Successful:

Check console output at http://xxx/34/ to view the results.

Changes:
${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="%a: %r %p \n--\"%m\", pathFormat="\n\t- %p"}
```

Why my script is not evaluated?

Comment: Because there were no changes ...https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20324

Comment: I put the script: {$CHANGES, reverse=true, default="no changes"} and now I got the following [Error replacing 'CHANGES' - Undefined parameter default in token CHANGES]

Comment: Sounds like you have an old version of email-ext installed.